# How to use MATLAB's data cursor via my code

Tags: matlab, fft

I have written my script in Matlab to generate `FFT` for a simple DTMF dial tone. Here is how my plot currently looks like:

[image]

However, I would like to be able to add MATLAB's `data cursor` feature at the two maxima points as  depicted below:

[image]

How can I do that through my code (not via plot window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the documentation of [`datacursormode`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datacursormode.html?refresh=true), it is said explicitely that it's not possible:

> You place data tips only by clicking data objects on graphs. You cannot place them programmatically (by executing code to position a data cursor).

However, the site [undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/) explains very precisely how to achieve that, see the page [Controlling plot data-tips](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips). Sometimes, Matlab help does not say the whole thing under the hood...